# array index out of bounds when UITableViewCell tapped, with and without a didselectrowatindex method

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Like Title

More information - I am populating my view controller with

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showCalendars" {
        // Setup new view controller
        print("happening")
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! CalendarSelectionViewController
        for item in self.approvedCalendars {
            vc.sentCalendars.append(item)
        }
        vc.tableView.reloadData()
        vc.calendarDelegate = self
    }
}
```

and my view controller code looks like :

```
    import UIKit
    import EventKit

    class CalendarSelectionViewController: UITableViewController {

var sentCalendars: [EKCalendar]! = []
var calendarDelegate: selectCalendarDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "My Calendars"
    //tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.sentCalendars.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("calendarCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = sentCalendars[indexPath.row].title
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}   
    }
```

whenever i click on any uitableview cell, my application crashes and I receive "fatal error: Array index out of range".

I've tried printing out the indexPath.row in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and it prints the correct index, so why is this crashing? Is there a memory leak somewhere and the tableview is not showing the proper information? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the app crashed by in 'didSelectRiwAtIndexPath' method?  You don't seem to have any code there.  If you set a breakpoint there, is your data populated as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigated my storyboard, I had an unwind segue that wasn't being used and was causing a fatal error: array index out of bounds. Thanks for the help!